# Unity2D pushing and pulling object of different shapes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i am having trouble in my script, The player could only push a perfect square object. I added objects that are in L shape [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k50xH.png) and i was trying to add pull by getting the sides of the collider but it is not working
the object has 2 boxcolliders. since it is an Lshape when the player push it at the center of the L if goes to the wrong direction since my code is based on the magnitude of the position of the player and the pushable object

here is my code for the pushable objects

```
public class PushableObject : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Player player;
[SerializeField] private float speed = 2;
[SerializeField] private float distanceX = 2;
[SerializeField] private float distanceY = 2;
[SerializeField] List<PushableObject> objectsInArea = new List<PushableObject>();

private bool isPlayerColliding = false;
private bool isMoving = false;


public bool IsMoving
{
    get { return isMoving; }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isPlayerColliding && player.IsInteractingObject && isAnyOtherObjectMoving())
    {
        move();
        isMoving = true;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E))
        isMoving = false;
}

private void move()
{
    Vector2 direction = transform.position - player.transform.position;

    float x = Mathf.Abs(direction.x), y = Mathf.Abs(direction.y);

    direction.x = x > y ? direction.x : 0;
    direction.y = y > x ? direction.y : 0;

    Vector2 targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) + direction;

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private bool isAnyOtherObjectMoving()
{
    foreach(PushableObject po in objectsInArea)
    {
        if (po.IsMoving)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        isPlayerColliding = true;
    }

}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        isPlayerColliding = false;
    }
}
```

}